# Makefile - how to write dependency properly

Tags: c++, makefile

The idea is this: I have `SportsCar` derived from `Car`, a `Car` consists of an `Engine`, each time `Car.drive()` is called, it calls `Engine.consumeGas()`, which in turn creates a `Gas` object and calls `Gas.burn()`. As you can see in the source code below.

Each class has its own header file and cpp file. And I wrote a Makefile (for Microsoft's NMAKE program).

The dependency is like this:

```
test.exe: main.obj Car.obj SportsCar.obj Engine.obj Gas.obj

main.obj: main.cpp Car.h SportsCar.h
Car.obj: Car.cpp Car.h
SportsCar.obj: SportsCar.cpp SportsCar.h // Here is what went wrong
Engine.obj: Engine.cpp Engine.h Gas.h
Gas.obj: Gas.cpp Gas.h
```

Build the program and run `test.exe`, produced the output:

> Car drive
>
> Engine consuming gas
>
> Gas burning
>
> SportsCar drive
>
> Engine consuming gas
>
> Gas burning

The problem is if I delete the member `engine` from `Car` and delete the call `engine.consumeGas()` in `Car.drive()` and rebuild the whole program, **only `Car.cpp` and `main.cpp` are recompiled (SportsCar.cpp is not) and the linker won't complain at all.**

After rebuilding, run `test.exe` get the output:

> Car drive
>
> SportsCar drive
>
> Engine consuming gas
>
> Gas burning

Apparently this result has completely violated the semantics of C++.

If I write the dependency like this, the problem will be fixed.

```
SportsCar.obj: SportsCar.cpp SportsCar.h Car.h
```

So if I have one source file `A` which includes a header file `B`, which in turn includes another header file `C`, and in `A`, the class `C` is used, I have to say `A` depends on both `B` and `C`, not just `A` depends on `B`?

If the project is large enough, I'm afraid I'll get lost trying to find out which file depends on which file while writing a Makefile.

Code:

main.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"
#include "SportsCar.h"

int main()
{
    Car *car = new Car();
    car->drive();
    delete car;

    car = new SportsCar();
    car->drive();
    delete car;

    return 0;
}
```

Car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include "Engine.h"

class Car
{
protected:
    Engine engine;
public:
    virtual void drive();
    virtual ~Car();
};

#endif // CAR_H
```

Car.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Car::drive()
{
    cout << "Car drive" << endl;
    engine.consumeGas();
}

Car::~Car()
{
    // do nothing
}
```

SportsCar.h

```
#ifndef SPORTSCAR_H
#define SPORTSCAR_H

#include "Car.h"

class SportsCar : public Car
{

public:
    void drive();
};

#endif // SPORTSCAR_H
```

SportsCar.cpp

```
#include "SportsCar.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void SportsCar::drive()
{
    cout << "SportsCar drive" << endl;
    engine.consumeGas();
}
```

Engine.h

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

class Engine
{

public:
    void consumeGas();
};

#endif // ENGINE_H
```

Engine.cpp

```
#include "Engine.h"
#include "Gas.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Engine::consumeGas()
{
    cout << "Engine consuming gas" << endl;
    Gas g;
    g.burn();
}
```

Gas.h

```
#ifndef GAS_H
#define GAS_H

class Gas
{

public:
    void burn();
};

#endif // GAS_H
```

Gas.cpp

```
#include "Gas.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Gas::burn()
{
    cout << "Gas burning" << endl;
}
```

Comment: When making makefile dependencies, you only need to look at the #include in your code.

Comment: Hm. This would be (fairly) simple with gmake and gcc/clang, but with nmake and msvc it's surprisingly painful. Do you have to use nmake? I think this would be easier with msbuild.

Comment: @brianbeuning What do you mean by "the #include in your code", which #include should I account in? Which #include I shouldn't? In my example above, `SportsCar.cpp` doesn't have a `#include "Car.h"`, but it still has dependency on `Car.h`.

Comment: The compiler can generate the header dependencies from your code such it can be included in the makefile. At least GCC does this, using the options from the `-MM` option family.

Comment: @Wintermute you mean If I use GNU make this wouldn't be a problem? I haven't tried it yet. But I think it's reasonable for a building tool not to check the #include relation between files. I thought it would be a problem with GNU make, too.

Comment: It is, but gcc and clang have a compiler option that generates a make-compatible list of dependencies that you can then `sinclude` in the makefile. That makes dependency tracking possible and not terribly hard. The Microsoft compiler does not appear to have that (or I'm too stupid to find it).

Comment: If a `Car` has an `Engine`, then it is likely that `Car.obj` depends on `Engine.h`. But your makefile doesn't have that dependency.

Comment: @juanchopanza I checked the code again...You're right, my mistake...but this doesn't affect my question...

Comment: Ovbiously `Sportscar.obj` should depend on `Car.h` for the similar reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You should generally never hardcode dependencies into makefiles. Instead, you should use the `-M -MF` flags to generate the dependencies during compilation and `include` the resulting file into your `Makefile`. Otherwise your dependencies will *always* be out of sync with reality.

Sadly, automatic dependency generation is a complex topic which I can't explain here in full detail. Many of the details can be found in this article: [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)

Comment: Thanks. very useful answer. I'm reading this article, hopefully it will give me a nice clue of how to do it well.